# Calculating exact window height using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am redesigning my website: http://staging.slackrmedia.com/keenanpayne/, but I am coming across a small issue. I want each "pane" of the website to be the exact height of the window, no matter what the size. I also want the content therein to be exactly positioned in the center.

I am trying to accomplish this with jQuery at the moment:

```
function setSectionHeight() { 
    // Set section heights
    windowHeightPadding = $(window).height() / 2;
    firstSectionPadding = ($(window).height() - $('header').height()) / 2;

    // Apply proper styling
    $('section').css({"padding-top":windowHeightPadding,"padding-bottom":windowHeightPadding});
    $('section.home').css({"padding-top": firstSectionPadding,"padding-bottom":windowHeightPadding});
}

setSectionHeight();

// Adjust section heights on window resize
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    setSectionHeight();
});
```

So what this is doing is calculating the window height and dividing it by 2, so I can set the top and bottom padding on each section.

However, for the first section, to get the proper top and bottom padding, I need to subtract the height of the header, which is why I have a `firstSectionPadding` variable.

Then I just add the CSS to each `section` tag on my website, with separate styling for the home `section` tag.

This works pretty well, but as you can see when you visit my site, for some reason the heights are not correct.

Right now it looks like: 
[image: Incorrect section height]

And it should look like: 
[image: Correct section height]

I have absolutely no idea where this extra padding or space is coming from on the top. I think my equations are right, but perhaps there isn't something I'm taking into consideration?

Comment: I see that on all sections you have the same `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`, except on the first one where you have `padding-top: 223.5px;`. Could this have to do something with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with CSS. One div set to 100% height and width, with text-align:center; A second div within set to display:table and 100% height and width. Finally, a third div set to display:table-cell and vertical-align:center;

Comment: You're the bomb. I tried something similar earlier but I was missing the third div set to `display: table-cell`. Thank's a lot!